# I messed up on my tax return... what do I do now?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, income-tax-refund, mistakes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I fix a mistake I made on my income tax filing? [US]](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/1681/how-can-i-fix-a-mistake-i-made-on-my-income-tax-filing-us)

So I just did some recalculating on my taxes and realized that I made a gross error (in my favor fortunately).  What are the proper steps to fixing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the US, you just file an amended return. TurboTax will even do it (probably other tax software will too). See http://www.irs.gov/taxtopics/tc308.html for details.

> If you discover an error after your return has been mailed, you may need to amend your return. The service center may correct errors in math on a return and may accept returns with certain forms or schedules left out. In these instances, do not amend your return! However, do file an amended return if your filing status, your income, your deductions or credits are incorrect